# java resultSet not updatable

Tags: java, database

i have a problem in resultset  when i made update on value inside database and i have primarykey inside my db 
this is the exception that i have

```
com.mysql.jdbc.NotUpdatable: Result Set not updatable
```

> protected void processPairWords()
>         {
>
> ```
>        int count1=0;
>       try {
>           Statement st1; 
>           Statement st2; 
>
>           st1 = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
>                      ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
>            st2 = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
>                      ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
>           ResultSet res1 = st1
>          .executeQuery("SELECT txt,freq,prob FROM searchtb WHERE txttype=1");
>
>           ResultSet res2= st2
>          .executeQuery("SELECT txt,freq,prob FROM searchtb WHERE txttype=2");
>           res1.beforeFirst();
>           res2.beforeFirst();
>
>           while (res1.next()){  
>               while(res2.next())
>               {
>                if(res2.getString("txt").startsWith(res1.getString("txt")))
>                   {
>                       int prob2=res2.getInt("freq");
>                       int prob1=res1.getInt("freq");
>                       double prob=prob2/prob1; 
>                        res2.updateDouble("prob", prob); 
>                           res2.updateRow();       
>                           count1++;
>                           System.out.println(res2.getString("txt"));
>
>                   }                   }
>                System.out.println("loop1");
>           }
>
>        conn.commit(); 
>           System.out.println("pairs count"+count1 );
>       } catch (SQLException e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       } 
>   }
> ```

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-updatable-resultset-in-jdbc/179

Comment: ddl for searchtb? And, I am probably wrong, but don't you have to return the primary key as part of the query in order for it to be updatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the table should have a primary key and the SQL query should select it.
Hope this can help you.